# Replace a string in textarea with emoji | VueJS

Tags: performance, vue.js, replace, emoji

I have a textarea for a message where some strings like ":-)" should be replaced with an emoji like . The textarea has a v-model on the 'message'-data property.

I added a function in the watch method:

```
  watch: {
message: function() {
  this.message = this.message.replace(":-)", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(":-(", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(";-)", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(":-|", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(":'-(", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(":-*", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace("*.*", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(";-P", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace("8-)", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace(":-D", "");
  this.message = this.message.replace("=-D", "");
}
},
```

The problem is - on my MacBook Pro and on my iPhone this runs like a charm. But many other users (Windows 10 with Chrome, Firefox, etc.) have problems with a delay when they are typing a message. How can I optimize this use case, so that everybody can work at normal speed?

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
watch: {
  message: function() {
    const replacements = {
      ":-)": "",
      ":-(": "",
      ";-)": "",
      ":-|": "",
      ":'-(": "",
      ":-*": "",
      "*.*": "",
      ";-P": "",
      "8-)": "",
      ":-D": "",
      "=-D": ""
    }
    Object.keys(replacements).forEach(k => {
      this.message = this.message.replace(k, replacements[k])
    })
  }
}
```